# IBM Worklight 6.1 - Migration error when importing a Worklight v5.0.5 project

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I am trying to migrate a worklight project from worklight version 5.0.5 to version 6.1. When i import the worklight application i get the following error:

```
Migrating the module_07_12_JSONStore_with_Security project from version 5.0.5 to version 6.1.0.0 has failed because Failed 
reading build-settings.xml
```

How to resolve this error?

Comment: For example i am trying to import the sample module from worklight v 5.0.0.5 in the eclipse with the worklight v 6.1.Then the project automatically converts to a folder like form rather than a worklight application

Comment: @Idan Adar I wanted to check how to migrate a worklight application version 5.0.5 application to worklight version 6.1 because i have a requirement for that. So i am checking the above implementation with samples. I want to know how to migrate worklight application version 5.0.5 to worklight v 6.1 eclipse . If i import the same then the above behaviour is happening.

Comment: I have created a new project in Worklight 5.0.5 and imported it successfully to Worklight 6.1; please provide a download link to the project you are trying to import.

Comment: @Idan Adar Do you have solution for the above error

Comment: I need you to provide a download link to the project where this is happening to you. Otherwise I cannot help.

Comment: @Idan Adar You can you use any sample module's provided in ibm information center for worklight v 5.0.0.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse may have a small problem .So re- install eclipse and worklight ,it may solve your problem. Try it before raising flag or downvote.

Answer (score 0):

I have imported the project [module_07_12_JSONStore_with_Security from Worklight 5.0.5.1](ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v505/wl_gs_all_samples.zip) into Worklight 6.1.0 and the project was successfully migrated:

> FWLST1022I: Starting to migrate the module_07_12_JSONStore_with_Security project from version 5.0.5 to
>   version 6.1.0.0. 
>   FWLPL0025I: The module_07_12_JSONStore_with_Security project is being saved as C:\WorklightDev\Eclipse\Workspaces\6100\module_07_12_JSONStore_with_Security\module_07_12_JSONStore_with_Security_2014_02_11_130543.backup.zip file.
>   FWLST1078I: **'build-settings.xml' file added to 'apps' application**
>   Created file 'default.keystore' in directory 'C:\WorklightDev\Eclipse\Workspaces\6100\module_07_12_JSONStore_with_Security\server\conf\default.keystore' of project 'module_07_12_JSONStore_with_Security' 
>   FWLST1106I: Adding default Worklight Analytics properties to the Worklight properties files. 
>   FWLPL0018I: Migrating the module_07_12_JSONStore_with_Security project from version 5.0.5 to version 6.1.0.0 has **succeeded**.

Please try downloading the .zip file from the link I have mentioned above. Then import the project you want into a fresh new workspace in Worklight 6.1.0 and see if it fails still.

Comment: The following errors are coming when i try to import from the link                                                    you have given                                                     E: Migrator class com.worklight.upgrader.upgraders.misc.ProjBuildSettingsUpgrader has failed 
[2014-02-11 17:18:51] FWLPL0019E: Migrating the module_07_12_JSONStore_with_Security project from version 5.0.5 to version 6.1.0.0 has failed because Failed 
reading build-settings.xml

Comment: Yes, that's the error you're getting from the question, but I am unable to recreate this... I continue to try, but so far w/out luck. Is there anything special in your environment? write permissions missing? anything?

Comment: I am searching for that only.But couldnt find answer.

Comment: Do you have solution for the above problem.Any idea how could we solve the problem

Comment: Like I wrote before, it is working for me. I am unsure why it is happening to you; Verify that you have full read & write permissions in your filesystem. Try in another computer. Try installing eclipse in the Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to your `temp` directory and delete the `wlBuildResources` folder. Re-build of the project should fix this issue.